# Parameter passed from Aura Controller is empty, when it reaches the Apex Class

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to invoke an Apex class method from an Aura Controller (the component itself has `controller="myController"`)

```js
({
    doInit: function (component) {
        var action = component.get("c.saveRecord");

        action.setParams({
            record: {
                Name__c: "Test"
            }
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();

            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                console.log(method + " response:", response.getReturnValue());
            } else {
                console.error("Error while executing " + method, response.getError());
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

The Apex class looks something like this:

```
public with sharing class myController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string saveRecord(namespace__MyCustomRecord__c record) {
        insert myCustomRecord;
        return myCustomRecord.Id;
    }
```

Observing the Network tab, I can verify that the correct data is sent as params. However, when it reaches the `saveRecord` method, the object is empty (`{}`), so an empty record is created (all fields are empty, except the created by)

The controller is exact replica of an old controller, used for @RemoteAction-s, they are able to read and write the custom object.

The controller is part of an Managed Package.

Any ideas?

I've verified that my role (System Administrator) is able to view/edit the fields.

I've also tried the JSON encode/decode approach, which is giving me `No such column 'Name__c' on sobject of type namespace__MyCustomRecord__c` error.

Comment: What happens when you pass a more "proper" representation of the sObject? `record: {sobjectType: 'namespace__MyCustomRecord__c', Name__c: 'Test'}`?

Answer (score 0):

"the morning is wiser than the evening"

It turned out that I should prefix my columns/fields names with my namespace as well.